# Suppress logging by cloudstorage.open() in google app engine GCS client library Python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, logging, google-cloud-storage

I'm using the GCS client library to write files to Google Cloud Storage in my App Engine app in Python.

Before creating a file, I need to make sure it doesn't already exist to avoid overwriting.

To do this I am checking to see if the file exists before trying to create it:

```
import cloudstorage as gcs

try:
    gcs_file = gcs.open(filename, 'r')
    gcs_file.close()
    return "File Exists!"
except gcs.NotFoundError as e:
    return "File Does Not Exist: " + str(e)
```

cloudstorage.write() is logging (either directly or indirectly) the fact that it receives a 404 error when trying to read the non-existent file. I would like to suppress this if possible.

Thanks

**edit**
Here's what is logged:

> 12:19:32.565 suspended generator _get_segment(storage_api.py:432)
>   raised NotFoundError(Expect status [200, 206] from Google Storage. But
>   got status 404. Path:
>   '/cs-mailing/bde24e63-4d31-41e5-8aff-14b76b239388.html'. Request
>   headers: {'Range': 'bytes=0-1048575', 'x-goog-api-version': '2',
>   'accept-encoding': 'gzip, *'}. Response headers:
>   {'alternate-protocol': '443:quic', 'content-length': '127', 'via':
>   'HTTP/1.1 GWA', 'x-google-cache-control': 'remote-fetch', 'expires':
>   'Mon, 02 Jun 2014 11:19:32 GMT', 'server': 'HTTP Upload Server Built
>   on May 19 2014 09:31:01 (1400517061)', 'cache-control': 'private,
>   max-age=0', 'date': 'Mon, 02 Jun 2014 11:19:32 GMT', 'content-type':
>   'application/xml; charset=UTF-8'}. Body: "`NoSuchKey`The specified
>   key does not exist.". Extra info: None.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logging in your case was triggered by str(e).
Issue was fixed in https://code.google.com/p/appengine-gcs-client/source/detail?r=172

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't understand how logging is triggered by str(e)? I removed it but the logging continues. Will the revision you linked to be part of the standard SDK soon or do I have to update the code myself? I'm less comfortable doing the latter.

Comment: This code is provided as a library and not part of the AppEngine SDK. Therefore you should update your code to the latest version:

https://code.google.com/p/appengine-gcs-client/

There aren't too many files and I don't think the differences are that many from the version you are probably working with already.